# How to get the error message during a jquery post while using aps.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using 2019 ASP.NET MVC with jquery 3.4.1. I'm trying to get the error message when I make a jquery ajax post. To simulate an error I mispelled the method in the controller being called by ajax. The best I could do was to display an alert box with some HTML code. It looks like the title tag contains the correct error message: "The resource cannot be found." But it's nested inside of a bunch of html code.

Is there a way to get that error message out of that html code and into a string?

Edit: I figured it out. I just added a span tag and set the html property of it.

Controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            //view
            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DoSomething1111111111()
        {
            return Json("hello");

        }


    }

}
```

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<input type="button" id="test-button" value="test" />

<span id="message"></span>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script>
 
    //test-button click event
    $(document).on("click", "#test-button", function () {

        //post
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/DoSomething",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (res) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (res) {
                 $("#message").html(res.responseText);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML response?

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't realize that whole thing was actually the error message in html format. I just added a span tag and populated the html property of it.

Comment: Great. Have a nice day, Madison. 